# Access Cache Data Error

Tags: ros-kinetic, message-filters, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the code I have written for question [#Q335276](https://answers.ros.org/question/335268/how-to-store-two-data-of-consecutive-frames-for-computation/?answer=335276#post-id-335276),
when I try to use the Cache methods, they weren't there. I am not sure why I am getting the error message as shown below:

```
[ERROR] [1571210224.306722]: bad callback: <bound method Subscriber.callback of <message_filters.Subscriber object at 0x7f226a827208>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 75, in callback
    self.signalMessage(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 57, in signalMessage
    cb(*(msg + args))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 134, in add
    self.signalMessage(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 57, in signalMessage
    cb(*(msg + args))
  File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/transmit_thrust/scripts/OptitrackReceive.py", line 119, in ReturnRateData
    self.rate_previous = Cache.getElemBeforeTime(Cache.getOldestTime())
AttributeError: 'PoseStamped' object has no attribute 'getElemBeforeTime'
```

Here is my code I am using for the Cache method:

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from std_msgs.msg import String
# from transmit_thrust.msg import RotorsAction
from transmit_thrust.msg import ThrustAction
from mavros_msgs.msg import ActuatorControl
# The message filters are used to calculate consecutive frames of messages received
import message_filters

class OptitrackReceive():
    
    def __init__(self):

        self.pos_original = PoseStamped()
        self.pos_converted = PoseStamped()
        self.rate_previous = PoseStamped()
        self.rate_current = PoseStamped()
        self.rotMatrix = np.zeros((3,3))
        self.rotMatrixComp = np.zeros((3,3))
        self.eulerAngle = np.zeros((3))
        self.linear_velocity = np.zeros((3))
        self.angular_velocity = np.zeros((3))
        
        rospy.Subscriber('/vrpn_client_node/TestTed/pose',
                         PoseStamped, self.transform)

        rospy.Subscriber('/vrpn_client_node/TestTed/pose',
                         PoseStamped, self.frameConversion)

        rospy.Subscriber('/vrpn_client_node/TestTed/pose',
                         PoseStamped, self.ReturnRotMatrix)

        self.sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/vrpn_client_node/TestTed/pose',PoseStamped)

        cache = message_filters.Cache(self.sub, 2,allow_headerless=False)

        cache.registerCallback(self.ReturnRateData)
        

    def frameConversion(self, data):
        
        Original = np.zeros((3,1))
        
        # Flip the y axis
        Original[0] = data.pose.position.x
        Original[1] = data.pose.position.y
        Original[2] = data.pose.position.z
        
        # Rotate counter clockwise around z by 90
        Ry = tf3d.euler.euler2mat(0,-math.pi*0.5,0,'sxyz')

        Original = np.dot(Ry,Original)

        data.pose.position.x = Original[0]
        data.pose.position.y = Original[1]
        data.pose.position.z = Original[2]
        
        self.pos_converted = data
        

    def transform(self, data):
        data.pose.position.x, data.pose.position.z = data.pose.position.z, data.pose.position.x
        
        self.pos_original = data
        #print(data)

    def ReturnRotMatrix(self, data):
        # The RotMatrix have to be from quaternions and therefore be converted to quaternions 
        # To be done
        euler = self.ReturnEulerAngle(data)

        self.eulerAngle = np.rad2deg(euler)

        self.rotMatrix = tf3d.taitbryan.euler2mat(euler[2],euler[1],euler[0])

        self.rotMatrixComp = tf3d.quaternions.quat2mat([data.pose.orientation.w, data.pose.orientation.x, data.pose.orientation.y, data.pose.orientation.z])


    def ReturnEulerAngle(self, data):
        # This converts the data quaternion type to euler angle type
        Orientation_list = np.zeros((4))

        Orientation_list[0] = data.pose.orientation.w
        Orientation_list[1] = data.pose.orientation.x
        Orientation_list[2] = data.pose.orientation.y
        Orientation_list[3] = data.pose.orientation.z
        
        # euler from quaternion
        eulerAngle = tf3d.taitbryan.quat2euler(Orientation_list)

        # Euler angle is yaw pitch roll after eulerAngle needed to convert 
        # to roll pitch yaw by swapping

        eulerAngle = np.flip(np.asarray(eulerAngle))

        eulerAngle[0] = - eulerAngle[0]

        return eulerAngle

    def ReturnRateData(self, Cache):   

        self.rate_previous = Cache.getElemBeforeTime(Cache.getOldestTime())
        self.rate_current = Cache.getElemAfterTime(Cache.getLatestTime())

        # Use the previous to obtain the angular rates in euler angles 
        euler_Previous = self.ReturnEulerAngle(data=self.rate_previous)

        euler_Current = self.ReturnEulerAngle(data=self.rate_current)    

        Timeframe = self.rate_current.header.stamp - self.rate_previous.header.stamp

        self.linear_velocity[0] = (self.rate_current.pose.position.x - self.rate_previous.pose.position.x) / Timeframe

        self.linear_velocity[1] = (self.rate_current.pose.position.y - self.rate_previous.pose.position.y) / Timeframe

        self.linear_velocity[2] = (self.rate_current.pose.position.z - self.rate_previous.pose.position.z) / Timeframe

        # Roll angular rate rads-1
        self.angular_velocity[0] = (euler_Current[0] - euler_Previous[0]) / Timeframe

        # Pitch Angle rate rads-1
        self.angular_velocity[1] = (euler_Current[1] - euler_Previous[1]) / Timeframe

        # Yaw Angle
        self.angular_velocity[2] = (euler_Current[2] - euler_Previous[2]) / Timeframe

# If execution is needed will run after this line
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    rospy.init_node('optitrack', anonymous=True)

    # This call initialises the class
    receiveData = OptitrackReceive()

    
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        # rospy.loginfo("Velocity: \r\n" + str(receiveData.velocity))
        rospy.loginfo("Position: \r\n" + str(receiveData.pos_converted.pose.position))
        rospy.loginfo("Orientation: \r\n" + str(receiveData.eulerAngle))
        rospy.loginfo("Rotational Matrix \r\n" + str(receiveData.rotMatrix))
        rospy.loginfo("Rotational Matrix from Quat: \r\n" + str(receiveData.rotMatrixComp))
         

        rate.sleep()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335459/access-cache-data-error/) by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: you create a special `message_filters.Subscriber`, which you pass to `message_filters.Cache`. This will cause the `Cache` to be updated with *every* incoming message. In addition, you register your own callback (ie: `self.ReturnRateData`) that also gets called for every new incoming message.

But that callback is a regular ROS subscribers callback, so it receives the message that was received by the special `Subscriber` you created earlier.

In your callback signature, you call that argument `Cache`, and treat it as if it is the `message_filters.Cache` instance (by calling `getElemBeforeTime(..)` on it).

That won't work, as it's actually a `geometry_msgs.PoseStamped` message (that was just received).

You'll have to keep a reference to `cache` around and access *that* in your `ReturnRateData(..)` (perhaps store your `Cache` instance as a member variable of your `OptitrackReceive` class).

---

Longer: you have this:

```
def __init__(self):
  [..]
  self.sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/vrpn_client_node/TestTed/pose',PoseStamped)
  cache = message_filters.Cache(self.sub, 2,allow_headerless=False)
  cache.registerCallback(self.ReturnRateData)

[..]

def ReturnRateData(self, Cache):
  self.rate_previous = Cache.getElemBeforeTime(Cache.getOldestTime())
  self.rate_current = Cache.getElemAfterTime(Cache.getLatestTime())
  [..]
```

The `Cache` argument that `ReturnRateData(..)` receives is not a `message_filters.Cache`, but a `PoseStamped`.

This is described on the wiki page of `message_filters` ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache)):

> ```
> sub = message_filters.Subscriber('my_topic', sensor_msgs.msg.Image)
> ```

```
cache = message_filters.Cache(sub, 100)
```

> In this example, the Cache stores the last 100 messages received on `my_topic`, and `myCallback` is called on the addition of every new message. The user can then make calls like `cache.getInterval(start, end)` to extract part of the cache.

And from the *Message Filters API documentation* ([here](https://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/#message_filters.Cache)):

> `message_filters.Subscriber.registerCallback(cb, *args)`
>
> Register a callback function cb to be called when this filter has output. The filter calls the function `cb` with a filter-dependent list of arguments, followed by the call-supplied arguments `args`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-10-16**:
@gvdhoorn: Thanks for the reply. I solved my problem with the following code:

```
self.sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/vrpn_client_node/TestTed/pose',PoseStamped)

self.cache = message_filters.Cache(self.sub, 2,allow_headerless=False)

self.cache.registerCallback(self.ReturnRateData)
```

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-10-16**:
And:

```
self.rate_previous = self.cache.getElemBeforeTime(self.cache.getOldestTime())

self.rate_current = self.cache.getElemAfterTime(self.cache.getLatestTime())
```